# Handling error in fatfree framework

Tags: php, error-handling, fat-free-framework

just a silly question, how to use error handling in f3 framework?

```
$this->f3->set('ONERROR', function($f3) {
      echo $this->f3->get('ERROR.text');
});

if (a > b) {
  //throw error  
  i want to call error and pass "a is too big!"
}
```

Comment: it work but i was expecting a html formatted error page like normally fatfree does.
https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/blob/master/lib/base.php#L1222

Comment: If this works then why not just use it? In other words why do you need a custom error handler if the one defined in FFF is formats the message?

Comment: is because it the format defined in f3 work only sometime not always, it's a bug?

Comment: The format may be different if the request comes from AJAX or cli. AJAX is used when there is a `X-Requested-With` header in the request

Comment: @george007 i don't use ajax now, but it seem to be random

Comment: Random for the same request or random for different requests (but the same for each request)?

Answer (score 1):

Just call the framework [error](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/base#error) method, with the appropriate [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes):

```
$f3->error(400,'a is too big');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like `throw new Exception("a is too big!")`

Here's an example that fits your case perfectly:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
if ($a > $b) {
  trigger_error("a is too big!", E_USER_NOTICE);
}
```

Comment: Why? You probably should increase level to `E_USER_ERROR`.